# What is cisvc.exe and why is it consuming so much CPU time?

Tags: cpu-usage

I see that `cisvc.exe` is taking up about 50% of my CPU time.  It has consumed 14 hours of CPU time out of 30 since the last restart.

- What is this process?
- How can I see why it is consuming so much CPU time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is fully explained in this article :

[What is Cisvc.exe and why does it slow down my computer](http://tech.blorge.com/Structure:%20/2009/02/15/what-is-cisvcexe-and-why-does-it-slow-down-my-computer/)

The comments for this article are also quite useful.

Comment: considering links go stale, could you consider expanding this into a standalone answer?

Comment: @Journeyman Geek: The article is much too long for that. Remark that links never go stale because the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/) is there, and it's not the only one.

Comment: @harrymc Wayback Machine does not archive everything. Some sites forbid robots and WM considers itself a robot. What are the others if WM is not the only one?